# $.Post with Form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

...Some form gets submitted...

`$.("form").submit(function() {

    saveFormValues($(this), "./../..";
}`

`function saveFormValues(form, path) {

    var inputs = getFormData(form);

    var params = createAction("saveFormData", inputs);

    var url = path + "/scripts/sessions.php";

    $.post(url, params);

}`


The weird thing is that if i add a function to the 

`$.post(url, params, function(data) {

    alert(data);
}`


I get a blank alert statement.

Within scripts/sessions.php i have a function to save whatever the $_POST information is to a file, and the sessions.php never saves this saveFormValues call.  It never shows up to the file.  But if i keep trying to get it to save, about once every 15 will actually allow it to be saved.  This leads me to believe that the forms POST is somehow blocking this value saving post.  Any help?

Comment: the `saveFormValues($(this), "./../../";' is actually `saveFormValues($(this), "./../../");'

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the original submit by returning false from the handler.  **Update**: If you want the original form submission to continue, then you can remove the handler and re-submit the form from the post callback.

```
$.("form").submit(function() {
    saveFormValues($(this), "./../..");
    return false; // cancels original submit and allows AJAX post to complete
});

function saveFormValues(form, path) {
    var inputs = getFormData(form);
    var params = createAction("saveFormData", inputs);
    var url = path + "/scripts/sessions.php";
    $.post(url, params, function() {
       $('form').unbind('submit').trigger('submit');
    });
}
```

Comment: @tvanfosson if only there were a way on SO to see when another user is updating his answer, would of saved me time!

Comment: @Michael  - you might want to consider simply doing the validation via AJAX instead of saving the values.  That seems more reasonable to me than allowing it to post with incorrect values.

Comment: Ok this does work, except there is one problem.  With this i need to hit the submit button 2x... Everytime.  I cannot get it to submit on its first try, but on its second try.

Comment: @tvanfosson  One thing i do is i have a few fields that are hidden per form and i do not want to have a huge if statement NOT saving those values to the session information, instead i am able, with jQuery, just remove any form fields with this.type != "hidden" and i can then save only the fields i want to be saved for the user.  So if there is an error with the actual form submission, then the old values are added back else the old values are removed since submission was successful.  If there is a significantly simpler way to do this, ill be excited. :)

Comment: @Michael, you might need to use trigger instead of submit in the callback.

Comment: @Michael - I guess I'm still not understanding doing the AJAX post and then a real submit of the same form.  If you're saving the values via the AJAX post, then why not just redirect to whatever page you want to end up on instead of going on to perform the submit again.  Or, as I suggested, just do validation via AJAX, remove the fields on successful validation, and do the full postback.  I'd probably be safe and check/remove the hidden fields anyway just in case javascript is disabled -- in that case, the full post will happen no matter what code you have on the client.

Answer (score 0):

add a `return false;` to the submit function to prevent the form from submitting:

```
$.("form").submit(function() {
saveFormValues($(this), "./../.."); return false });
```

UPDATE:

if you want to later submit the form, keep a variable to indicate if it can be submitted:

```
var canSubmit = false;
$.("form").submit(function() {
    if(!canSubmit)
    {
        saveFormValues($(this), "./../..");
        return false;
    }
});
```

and later:

```
$.post(url, params, function(data) {
    alert(data); 
    canSubmit = true; 
    $.("form").submit();
}
```

Comment: But i want the form to be submitted as well, but if there is any errors the information is first saved.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of doing a $.post i tried doing a $.ajax with asynch set to false.  It saves the form values every ... like 3/5 times... any new suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So i decided to create an associative list of items that will not be saved from a form.

`$nosave = array("password" => true, "confirmPassword" => true,
                    "descriptionCount" => true, "detailedDescriptionCount" => true,
                    "submit" => true, "action" => true, "p" => true);
//Then i decided to go through the $_POST information and save it to the SESSION info.

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

            if ($key != $id && !array_key_exists($key, $nosave)) {

                //saves the value to the form.

                $_SESSION[$id][$key] = $value;

            }

        }`

//The $id is a hidden input.. name="formId" value="someUniqueId" That way whenever
//the form info is saved, its saved under a unique area and can be easily unset.

Instead of doing it through jQuery, i just called a function that roughly does all of that in my sessions.php file.